# PySpark When item in list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Following is the action I'm trying to achieve:

```
types = ["200","300"]
def Count(ID):
    cnd = F.when((**F.col("type") in types**), 1).otherwise(F.lit(0))
    return F.sum(cnd).alias("CountTypes")
```

The syntax in bold is not correct, any suggestions how to get the right syntax here for PySpark?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve but here is the correct syntax :

```
types = ["200","300"]
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cnd = F.when(F.col("type").isin(types),F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))
sum_on_cnd = F.sum(cnd).alias("count_types")
# Column<b'sum(CASE WHEN (type IN (200, 300)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `count_types`'>
```

Comment: thx it works, I'm trying to do the same thing on a list of lists meaning each item in types is a tuple for example. It doesn't allow using isin with list/tuples. Any idea how to overcome it?