# PySpark: Populating a column based on the last occurance of one of the values in a different column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Using PySpark, I am looking for a way to populate a column `Status` based on values in the column `Code`. The df is ordered by the `ID` column.

The only significant `Code` values are `A (Good), B (Bad), C (Neutral)`.

When one of those values appears then I would like every single further row to have the same `Status` value until any of the other significant `Code` values appears.

This is the desireable df output with the newly added `Status` column:

```
+----+------+---------+
| ID | Code | Status  |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | A    | Good    |
|  2 | 1x4  | Good    |
|  3 | B    | Bad     |
|  4 | ytyt | Bad     |
|  5 | zix8 | Bad     |
|  6 | C    | Neutral |
|  7 | 44d  | Neutral |
|  8 | A    | Good    |
+----+------+---------+
```

I am not sure how to solve this, I found this question, but I don't know if the answer can be adapted to my needs: 
[PySpark When item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328352/pyspark-when-item-in-list)

I thought about using the lag function, but the number of rows between `A, B and C` rows is irregular, so I don't know how to bite this.

Here is the df for reproducibility:

```
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, A),
        (2, 1x4),
        (3, B),
        (4, ytyt),
        (5, zix8),
        (6, C),
        (7, 44d),
        (8, A)
    ],
    ('ID', 'Code')
)
```

Comment: I feel the 'merge' function can do this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `when` with a running `sum` to define groups (rows from the first occurrence of 'A','B' or 'C' codes until the next in the order of `id`). Then use the `first` value of the classified groups in `when` to get the status column.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum,when,first
w = Window.orderBy(df.id)
df_with_grp = df.withColumn('grp',sum(when(df.code.isin(['A','B','C']),1).otherwise(0)).over(w))
w1 = Window.partitionBy(df_with_grp.grp).orderBy(df_with_grp.id)
res = df_with_grp.withColumn('status',when(first(df_with_grp.code).over(w1) == 'A','Good') \
                                     .when(first(df_with_grp.code).over(w1) == 'B','Bad') \
                                     .when(first(df_with_grp.code).over(w1) == 'C','Neutral')
                            )
```

Answer (score 2):

First fill in the significant code values, using the following function:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions col, lit, when

def getStatus(code):
    return when(code=="A", lit("Good"))\
        .when(code=="B", lit("Bad"))\
        .when(code=="C", lit("Neutral"))

df = df.withColumn("Status", getStatus(col("Code")))
df.show()
#+---+----+-------+
#| ID|Code| Status|
#+---+----+-------+
#|  1|   A|   Good|
#|  2| 1x4|   null|
#|  3|   B|    Bad|
#|  4|ytyt|   null|
#|  5|zix8|   null|
#|  6|   C|Neutral|
#|  7| 44d|   null|
#|  8|   A|   Good|
#+---+----+-------+
```

Next use a Window function to pick the last non-null value of `"Status"` ordered by `"ID"`. We can pick out the last value using [`pyspark.sql.functions.last`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last) with `ignorenulls=True`.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions last
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = df.withColumn(
    "Status", 
    last(
        col("Status"),
        ignorenulls=True
    ).over(
        Window.partitionBy().orderBy("ID").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    )
)
df.show()
#+---+----+-------+
#| ID|Code| Status|
#+---+----+-------+
#|  1|   A|   Good|
#|  2| 1x4|   Good|
#|  3|   B|    Bad|
#|  4|ytyt|    Bad|
#|  5|zix8|    Bad|
#|  6|   C|Neutral|
#|  7| 44d|Neutral|
#|  8|   A|   Good|
#+---+----+-------+
```

Comment: by running code i am getting correct format but warning . `WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation` . Could you please explain.